# Get all child categories from nested set AND join products table

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, nested-lists

I want to retrieve all child categories with a given parent category AND I want to join my products table to that result. The result should be a breadcrumb navigation where a user could click on a parent category and retrieves all products in that category with the child categories.

Breadcrumb looks like that: `Electronic >> Music >> MP3-Player >> Flash`
If a user clicks on "Music" the result should contain all products in the "Music" "MP3-Player" and "Flash" categories.

I use a nested set but I find it  really difficult to handle it with complicated queries.

My database looks like that:

category_table: ID / Name / lft / rgt
products_table: ID / Title / description / pic / category_id / ...

My query looks now like this:

```
    $result=mysql_query('SELECT *, node.id, node.name
FROM category AS node,
        category AS parent,
        category AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.name
                FROM category AS node,
                category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                AND node.id = 23
                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree JOIN products ON products.id = id
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;') or die(mysql_error());
```

But this gives me the error "#1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay". I don't get it.

Comment: if you can do the change to DB, I suggest use "Breadcrumb" field in category table, and store comma seperated value of all parents in that field, then your search will be relatively easy and increase performance is added advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this PHP script. It may have a couple syntax errors in it, I haven't tested it yet, but it should do exactly what you want.

Its important to note, you need to add a field to your `categories` table, called `category_parent_id` and set its default value to either `0` or `null`.

```
class breadcrumbNav
{
    private $dataArray = array();
    private $breadcrumb = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->getAllRecords();
        return;
    }


    private function getAllRecords()
    {
        $result = $db->prepare("
            SELECT p.ID as product_id, p.title AS product_title, p.description AS product_description, p.pic AS product_picture, 
                   c.ID as category_id, c.Name as category_name, c.lft AS category_lft, c.rgt AS category_rgt, c.parent_id AS category_parent_id 
            FROM products p 
            LEFT JOIN categories c 
                 ON p.category_id = c.ID 
        ");

        $result->execute();

        $this->dataArray = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return;
    }

    function buildBreadcrumb($recordId, $firstRun = true)
    {
         foreach($this->dataArray as $row)
         {
             if(($row['product_id']==$recordId && $firstRun) || ($row['category_id']==$recordId && $firstRun===false))
             {
                  $this->breadcrumb[] = '<a href="?categoryId=' . $row['category_id'] . '">' . $row['category_name'] . '</a>';

                  if($row['category_parent_id']!==0 && !is_null($row['category_parent_id']))
                  {
                      $this->buildBreadcrumb($this->buildBreadcrumb($row['category_parent_id'], false));
                  }
             }
         }

         return implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $this->breadcrumb;
    }
}



$currentProductId = 'ENTER THE PRODUCT ID HERE';
$breadcrumbObject = new breadcrumbNav();
$breadcrumb = $breadcrumbObject->buildBreadcrumb($currentProductId);
```